# Convert ROW into column with their respective records

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, common-table-expression

Convert ROW into column with their respective records

i need 4 Columns

```
TYPE   |    COUNT    |    PERIOD     |   VARIANCE
TRADE      50               JAN            0%
TRADE      100              FEB            100%
```

i am using this query and getting three columns only

```
with b1 as
(
SELECT 

      COUNT(DISTINCT T.SALE)AS TRADE,
      TO_CHAR(T.DATE,'YYYY-MON') As Period
        FROm  TRADE T 
          JOIN ORDER O ON T.Account = O.Account
        WHERE
           T.DATE between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-01-31'  --Last 
                group by TO_CHAR(T.DATE,'YYYY-MON')

UNION ALL

SELECT 

      COUNT(DISTINCT T.SALE) AS TRADE,
      TO_CHAR(T.DATE,'YYYY-MON') As Period
        FROm  TRADE T 
          JOIN ORDER O ON T.Account = O.Account
        WHERE
           T.DATE between date '2020-02-01' and date '2020-02-28'  --Last 
         group by TO_CHAR(T.DATE,'YYYY-MON'))

select  TRADE, Period,
       100*(TRADE-lag(TRADE,1,TRADE) over (order by period))
       /lag(TRADE,1,TRADE) over (order by period)
       as "variance(%)"
  from b1
 order by period
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do.  Your sparse description of the problem has no relationship to the query you have posted.

Comment: That's because you're not calculating `count` in any of the queries. Please post input and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're really close. Is this what you're looking for?

```
with b1 as
(
SELECT 
 "TRADE" as Type,
      COUNT(DISTINCT T.SALE)AS Count,
      TO_CHAR(T.DATE,'YYYY-MON') As Period
        FROm  TRADE T 
          JOIN ORDER O ON T.Account = O.Account
        WHERE
           T.DATE between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-01-31'  --Last 
                group by TO_CHAR(T.DATE,'YYYY-MON')

UNION ALL

SELECT 
"TRADE" as TYPE,
      COUNT(DISTINCT T.SALE) AS COUNT,
      TO_CHAR(T.DATE,'YYYY-MON') As Period
        FROm  TRADE T 
          JOIN ORDER O ON T.Account = O.Account
        WHERE
           T.DATE between date '2020-02-01' and date '2020-02-28'  --Last 
         group by TO_CHAR(T.DATE,'YYYY-MON'))

select  TYPE, COUNT, Period,
       100*(TRADE-lag(TRADE,1,TRADE) over (order by period))
       /lag(TRADE,1,TRADE) over (order by period)
       as "variance(%)"
  from b1
 order by period
```